# Cambiar un propiedad de PictureBox a todos los que tengo en el formulario en C#

Tags: c#, picturebox

Tengo un panel con varias PictureBox. Cuando hago clic en una, cambia el borde y hago un tratamiento, el problema es revertir ese cambio en el borde cuando hago clic en otra PictureBox.
He probado este foreach pero no me cambia el borde, y como cambia el borde de la que clico no sé cuál es la activa.
¿Alguna idea?

```
void PictureBoxClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (sender is PictureBox pb)
            {
                foreach (PictureBox box in this.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>())
                {
                        box.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
                }
                pb.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
                NumeroSeleccionado = pb.Name;
                txtNumeroSeleccionado.Text = NumeroSeleccionado;
                MuestraDatos();
            }
        }
```

Comment: los picturebox que comentas los generas por código? están en la UI? puedes identificarlos?

Comment: Prueba de hacer un `Refresh` del control despues de cambiar la propiedad, para que se vuelva a "pintar" el control con esas propiedades cambiadas.
`box.Refresh()`

Comment: No, box.Refresh() no cambia nada.

Comment: Si, los genero por codigo y los veo y cuando pulso uno hace lo que le pido pero no vuele a BorderStyle.None; se queda marcado y cuantos mas pulso mas marco. La unica solucion por ahora es limpiar el panel y volver a cargarlos todos

Comment: Puedes mostrar el codigo de como generas los picturebox?

Comment: while ()
                    {
                        PictureBox pictureBox_miniatura = new PictureBox();
                        pictureBox_miniatura.Click += PictureBoxClicked;
                        pictureBox_miniatura.Size = new Size(9, 9);
                        pictureBox_miniatura.Location = new Point((7 + 2) * i, (7 + 2) * fila);
                        pictureBox_miniatura.Image = Image.FromFile(MidresImagen);
                        pictureBox_miniatura.Name = NumeroMiniatura;
}

Comment: No veo donde haces el `Controls.Add(pictureBox_miniatura);`

Comment: Es que no me deja, es demasiado largo

pictureBox_miniatura.Name = NumeroMiniatura;
//Esta linea agrega el pictureBox_miniatura al panel contenedor
panel1.Controls.Add(pictureBox_miniatura);

Comment: Ya lo he visto
Gracias.

Comment: foreach (PictureBox box in panel1.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>())

Comment: Si los añades todos en un panel, en el foreach de los pictureBox deberias recorrer los controles dentro del panel y no los controles del formulario:
`foreach (PictureBox box in panel1.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>())`

Comment: Cuando me pediste la linea de creacion, me di cuenta, gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema que tienes es que estas intentando buscar los `PictureBox` en el formulario, cuando los tienes colocados en un `Panel`, por lo tanto, el código debería quedarte de la siguiente manera:

```
foreach (PictureBox box in panel1.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>())
{
    box.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
}
```